# preview box in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a textarea and a preview box. When i type in textarea it will display in preview box.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function updateAdTextdValue()
{ 

var s = document.getElementById("sample_ad_text").value;

if( s=='Write here ...')
{
    s ="";
}


jQuery("#composeadd_display").html(s);
}

</script>


<textarea onchange="updateAdTextdValue()"  class="textarea" id="sample_ad_text" name="sample_ad_text" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Write here ...';this.style.color='#252525';}" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Write here ...') {this.value = '';this.style.color='#252525'}" style="width:250px; height:250px;">Write here ...</textarea>


<div class="composeadd_b" id="composeadd_display" style="overflow-y:auto; background-color: #F5F5F5;
float: left;
font-size: 13px;
height: 350px;
margin-right: 35px;
padding: 10px;
width: 285px;"> </div>
```

It is working . But  i want to display text to next line in preview box after 20 characters. Anybody please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

It will genertae your line in next line and give some space;

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function updateAdTextdValue()
{ 

var s   = document.getElementById("sample_ad_text").value;
var output='';

if( s=='Write here ...')
{
    s ="";
}
else 
{
         for(var i in s)
        {
            if(i > 0 && i%20 == 0)
                output += '<br>';
                output += s[i];
        }
    jQuery("#composeadd_display").html(output);
}    



}
    </script>
```

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLx8k/1/)

Comment: but how to count the number of characters. if(s%22==0){
jQuery("#composeadd_display").html('</br><p style="padding-left:20px"></p>'+s);
}
else
{

jQuery("#composeadd_display").html(s);
} I have write like this but it shows in same line

Comment: I need to be come to newline after each 20 characters